# Looking for favorite author of series YA fantasy in 70s

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

Looking for favorite author from Young Adult section of library, during early 70s. One plot involved a girl who was having trouble with her racial identity (she was half black) and while on a class trip to a museum, she is transported back to Egypt where she is a princess.

Comment: Right publishing time period, some details match, but it's probably not it: Mary Stolz, Cat in the Mirror.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds to me a bit like [Wraiths of Time](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0812547527) by Andre Norton. However the heroine, Tallahassee Mitford, is an archeologist and is transported back to ancient Egypt when she grasped an ancient artefact.

There must be lots of books using variations on this plot device.

Comment: The particular author was in the A -B section of the children's section because I remember it was to the left of the Carol Ryrie Brink books. Another book she did was about a girl who was a witch, set in the past, living with some persecuting Aunts. I think she runs away with a young man at the end, having found the confidence in herself.